Connecting to Spark Standalone Cluster from local jupyter notebook
I am learning how to run a spark cluster using docker compose.
I have successfully run the spark cluster container, but I am trying to connect to the spark master from my local jupyter notebook.
I am wondering if it is possible to do so? I can access SparkUI and my spark master is located in port 7077.
Below is the code I used to call the spark master.
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("practice") \
    .master("spark://<my-ip>:7077") \
    .getOrCreate()`

It throws
JAVA HOME IS NOT SET
PySparkRuntimeError: [JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED] Java gateway process exited before sending its port number.

but if I run it inside the container there's no issue, all working well as intended. Spark submit is also working fine.
I made sure the ip address is correct and tested if spark is working correctly in the container.
My aim was to connect to the spark cluster from my local jupyter notebook so that I could practice pyspark using the deployed spark container.
I am wondering if environment variable is important here.
Here is my os environ path in local. What is the correct path for SPARK_HOME since my spark is located inside the docker container.
'SPARK_HOME': '/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark',
'PYSPARK_PYTHON': '/usr/bin/python3'


As the error says, do you have Java installed? And JAVA_HOME environment variable is set?

@OneCricketeer I have it installed in my container for the spark cluster but not in local. do I need to have Java installed in local as well?

Yes. Spark needs Java to execute or submit client code
